# android menus clickable spans or textviews

Tags: android, menu, clickable

Are the android menus "clickable spans" or "clickable textviews" or other? Like these:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

And the "Done" in the second image, what is that?
EDIT: Is the 2nd image showing a dialog or a popup?

Answer (score 0):

Yes a TextView can be clickable you just have to attach an onClickListener to it.
The "Done" element is a button (one of android built-in widgets).